# Use RIA services domain service without Query method

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services

I created a LoggerDomainService witch look like this :

```
 [EnableClientAccess()]
public class LoggerDomainService : DomainService
{

    public void info()
    {
        // todo
    }
}
```

And after building the server side the LoggerDomainContext did not created.
I've noticed that in order to make it work I need to declare inside the class at least on method with the [Query] attribute.
Is there better way to solver the problem, should I inherit from something else then DomainService ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about the `[Query]` attribute. With your logging service, I recommend using `[Invoke]`:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class LoggerDomainService : DomainService
{
    [Invoke]
    public void info()
    {
        // todo
    }
}
```

Then you will find the context created.